# Special Issue with div displacement upon zooming out

Tags: css, html

EDIT:

On the above site whenever I zoom out in firefox the main content div is displaced to the right. This issue only exists in firefox, not in internet explorer, opera or chrome. Could someone help me fix this?

EDIT 2:

I do NOT want the div to displace in firefox. Sorry about the first question, I was in a hurry but should be clear now :)

Comment: Is that your site? Otherwise this isn't a question.

Comment: Yes, this is my site. As I already mentioned above I am having this issue that in firefox my websites main div displaces when zooming out. It would be nice of you if you could help me solve the issue...Thank you.

Comment: What are you asking for here?  Do you want it to displace to the right, like it does in Firefox, or do you want it not to?  You mention two browsers with only one result...

Comment: And why do you say it only exists in IE, when you describe the issue occurring in firefox?

Comment: Hey, im sorry my friend, it is my fault. The entire question did not make any sense at all. I was in a hurry because I had to check the oven!

Comment: That makes more sense... I was able to fix the problem, see below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you give float:left; to the .wrapper element and the ul.menu everything will be ok :)

Comment: hey, thank you my friend. I will try it out now and let you know if it worked and you will get your "accept". Thank you very much Matei!

Comment: The float:left worked but the issue is that the menu buttons are not aligned now :(

Comment: make a new class named .clear { clear:both; } and put a div between your menu and wrapper like <div class="clear"></div>. I hope this will be the solution

Comment: It worked! You were also so nice. Thank you so much for your help! I hope we stay in contact. Wish you the best.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are having is not with `#content` but rather with the class `wrapper`.  If you remove the rule `overflow:hidden` from the class, the issue will go away.  It looks like the wrapper class is also associated with your button bar.

I would suggest removing wrapper from the div which holds all of the page contents and instead use a rule which only has `width="100%"`.

Comment: I just tried to remove overflow hidden but it destroy the entire layout :( since I built it upon the wrapper.

Comment: You just needed to remove the wrapper class from the content div.